# Basic Pig Latin | Troubles with .each

Tags: ruby

I'm solving a basic training exercise and I got stuck. I have to *Move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add 'ay' to the end of the word.*. I've been googling and came up with this code:

```
 def pig_it translate_pig_latin   
    move_letters = text.split(' ')
                       .each do {|x| x[1..-1] << x.[0] << 'ay' }
    move_letters.join(' ') 
 end
```

But for some reason it gives me this error

> -e:4: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'
>       .each do {|x| x[1..-1] << x.[0] << 'ay' }

I know it's a problem with the `.each` method, but after reading the documentation and googling around I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: "I know it's a problem with the `.each` method" – No, it's not. It's a syntax error, which means the code isn't even syntactically valid Ruby. In other words, Ruby cannot even start to run your code, because it doesn't understand it, therefore which methods you call is completely and utterly irrelevant. In fact, one thing you can say *for sure* just from the fact that it is a syntax error without even looking at the error message or the code, is that it *cannot possibly* have anything to do with *any* method, `.each` or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def translate_pig_latin(text)
     move_letters = text.split(' ')
         .each { |x| return x[1..-1] << x[0] << 'ay' }
     move_letters.join(' ')     
end
```

Some notes -

- As another user stated, don't mix and match `do`/`end` and `{}`
- Also, when using bracket notation to retrieve an item from an array, don't use a `.` like you have in `x.[0]`
- Your `.each` block is doing the correct thing(when you adhere to the above note) but isn't returning the result (by which I am confused).  If you add an explicit `return` then your code works as above

A more drawn out method if this helps you understand what's happening better

```
    def translate_pig_latin(text)
        # create array to contain piglatinified phrase
        new_phrase = []
        # each word of the original phrase do
        text.split(' ').each do |x|
            # grab the characters after the first character
            new_word = x[1..-1]
            # add the first character plus 'ay' to the end of the string
            new_word << x[0] + 'ay'
            # add the newly piglatinified string to the phrase
            new_phrase << new_word
        end
        # turn the phrase into a space separated string
        new_phrase.join(' ') 
    end
```

Comment: Thanks fort a very thorough explanation, and for being so patient with those beginner errors :)

Answer (score 1):

Use *either* `do`...`end` *or* `{`...`}`.  Don't mix them with `do {` as you did. That line should look like this:

```
.each { |x| x[1..-1] << x[0] << 'ay' }
```

or

```
.each do |x| x[1..-1] << x[0] << 'ay' end
```

From a style perspective, most Rubyists prefer to use `{`...`}` for single-line blocks and reserve `do`...`end` for blocks that span multiple lines of code.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the original error but there are still problems with the function.  See my answer for a thorough breakdown